# Cargar en un DIV datos de Mysql mediante AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

estoy intentando que al pulsar el botón de editar se me carguen los datos de la base de datos. Los datos que se cargan dependen de la cantidad de filas que haya en la base de datos.
Por cada fila, tiene que crear esa cantidad de filas de inputs.

Este es el div donde se tienen que cargar los datos.

```
 <div class="row" id="cargaConceptos">
   <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" hidden="" id="numeroAlbaranConceptosU" name="">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Conceptos</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Esta es la función ajax.

```
function actualizarAlbaran(){

numeroAlbaran = $('#numeroAlbaranU').val();
idObraAlbaran = $('#idObraAlbaranU').val();
fechaAlbaran = $('#fechaAlbaranU').val();
idVehiculoAlbaran = $('#idVehiculoAlbaranU').val();
idResponsableAlbaran = $('#idResponsableAlbaranU').val();
kilometrosAlbaran = $('#kilometrosAlbaranU').val();

cadena = "numeroAlbaran=" + numeroAlbaran +
        "&idObraAlbaran=" + idObraAlbaran +
        "&fechaAlbaran=" + fechaAlbaran +
        "&idVehiculoAlbaran=" + idVehiculoAlbaran + 
        "&idResponsableAlbaran=" + idResponsableAlbaran +
        "&kilometrosAlbaran=" + kilometrosAlbaran;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "actualizarAlbaran.php",
            data: cadena,
            success: function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    $('#tabla_albaranes').load('tabla_albaranes.php');
                    alertify.success("Albaran actualizado");
                } else {
                    alertify.error("No se pudo actualizar");
                }
            }
        });


        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "cargarConceptos.php",
            data: {
            numeroAlbaranConceptos: $('#numeroAlbaranConceptosU').val()
            },
            success: function(r){
                
                var carga = document.getElementsById('cargaConceptos');
                carga.innerHTML = r;
                console.log(r);
            } 
            
        });
```

}
Esta función llama por GET al código PHP que es este:

```
<?php

require_once "bd/conexion.php";
$conexion = conexion();

$numeroAlbaran = $_GET['numeroAlbaranConceptos'];

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM l_albaran_conceptos WHERE N_ALBARAN ='$numeroAlbaran'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
$html='';

                            
                                
while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $html .= '<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-4"><label>ID<label><input type="text" value="'.$valores['id'].'"</input></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="col-md-4"><label>Nº Albaran<label><input type="text" value="'.$valores['N_ALBARAN'].'"</input></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="col-md-4"><label>ID Obra<label><input type="text" value="'.$valores['ID_OBRA'].'"</input></div></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><label>ID Operario<label><input type="text" value="'.$valores['ID_OPERARIO'].'"</input></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="col-md-4"><label>ID Concepto<label><input type="text" value="'.$valores['ID_CONCEPTO'].'"</input></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="col-md-4"><label>Horas<label><input type="text" value="'.$valores['HORAS'].'"</input></div></div>';
    

}

echo $html;

?>
```

Creo que tengo el error en la función ajax, a la hora de pintar los datos en el div, que no se muy bien si lo que tengo escrito es correcto.

Gracias de antemano.

Edit:
La función ajax está dentro de una función llamada actualizarAlbaran() que se ejecuta al hacer click en el botón actualizar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#btnActualizarAlbaran').click(function() {
        actualizarAlbaran();
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit2: He cambiado un error que tenía, y es que no le estaba pasando el id por ajax al php.
También he cambiado el carga.innerHTML = r.data; por carga.innerHTML = r;
Aun así sigue sin funcionar.
No me muestra el html y en la consola con console.log(r), tampoco muestra nada.

Edit3: He añadido la función javascript completa. Tiene otra función ajax dentro la cual si funciona perfectamente.
También he cambiado la forma de enviar los datos por esta

```
data: {
  numeroAlbaranConceptos: $('#numeroAlbaranConceptosU').val()
    },
```

Comment: ¿Por qué pones `r.data` aquí: `carga.innerHTML = r.data;` cuando los datos no vienen bajo ninguna clave llamada `data`?. Revisando tu código PHP, si la petición está funcionando, los datos estarían viniendo como HTML, por tanto con esto debería bastar: `carga.innerHTML = r;`. Si no funciona, pon un `console.log(r);` y revisa la consola.

Comment: @A.Cedano He editado la pregunta. No me muestra nada el console.log(r)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estás enviando correctamente los datos, suponiendo que el valor del campo es 5:

```
numeroAlbaranConceptos = $('#numeroAlbaranConceptosU').val();
cadena2 = "numeroAlbaranConceptos" + numeroAlbaranConcepto;
// Resultado: numeroAlbaranConceptos5
```

En PHP `$numeroAlbaran = $_GET['numeroAlbaranConceptos'];` resultará en error por tratar de acceder a un índice no definido.

Mejor crea un objeto y deja que [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) lo transforme por ti, ya que por defecto la propiedad `processData` es verdadero y hará que la petición se ejecute como `cargarConceptos.php?numeroAlbaranConceptos=5`:

```
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "cargarConceptos.php",
            // Crear objeto con nombre de variable y valor
            data: {
                numeroAlbaranConceptos: $('#numeroAlbaranConceptosU').val()
            },
            success: function(r) {
                
                var carga = document.getElementsById('cargaConceptos');
                carga.innerHTML = r;
                console.log(r);

                
            },
            // Agregar función para saber si hubo error
            error: function(xhr, status, message) {
                console.log(`Error en petición AJAX: ${status} - ${message}`);
            }
        });
```

Te sugiero agregar una pequeña validación en PHP para asegurar que tienes un valor en la variable, por medio de asignación ternaria y suponiendo que el valor esperado es un entero:

```
// Asegurar que tienes un valor entero
$numeroAlbaran = (isset($_GET['numeroAlbaranConceptos'])) ? intval($_GET['numeroAlbaranConceptos']) : 0;
// Validar
if($numeroAlbaran <= 0) {
    die('El número debe ser mayor que cero');
}
// Aquí ejecutas la consulta y continúas con el proceso normal
```

Comment: Hola, he hecho lo que me has dicho y envío el id de esa manera, pero sigue igual. También he añadido la validación de PHP pero no hace nada.

Comment: @aunkeseaunrato, modifiqué la respuesta para agregar una función donde puedes capturar errores, ahora sí debe aparecer algo en la consola, ya sea una cadena (puede estar vacía) o mensaje de error.

Comment: Sí, me muestra el error 'El número debe ser mayor que cero'

Comment: @aunkeseaunrato, entonces el valor del campo está vacío `<input type="text" hidden="" id="numeroAlbaranConceptosU" name="">`; ¿En qué momento lo actualizas?

Comment: Era eso. Estaba cogiendo el id que no era. He cogido el que sí estaba cargado y ha funcionado. Muchas gracias.